# mapply with zero length inputs. How to make it skip?

Tags: r, apply, mapply

I have 2 separate datasets with qualities of the same individuals: position and size. Position will change every hour according to size. Size will also change every hour, but it doesn't in this reprex. Anyway, I'm doing this in a loop that iterates every hour with `apply()` functions to change the next column of the matrices. I need helping making the functions work when none of the individuals meet those criteria during that loop iteration.

```
# here is a matrix of positions. the first column is the starting position,
# and this will change throughout, so second column is empty for now.
position <- cbind(c(10,20,10,20,10),c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)) 

# size of individuals. position in next column should change depending on size,
# such that small individuals (size < 5) will move up 5 positions, 
# and large individuals (> 8) will move down 7 positions. 
size <- c(2,2,3,8,8)

# for small individuals, add 5 to make next position
position[,2][ size < 5] <- mapply(sum,position[,1][size<5],5)  

# for large individuals, subtract 7 to make next position
position[,2][ size > 8 ] <- mapply(sum,position[,1][size > 8],-7)
```

I keep getting stuck when a condition has 0 occurrences. In this case, there are no individuals with size > 8, so the `mapply()` function doesn't work. It gives me the error:

```
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length
```

Is there a way to make an `mapply()` function just do nothing if one of the inputs is zero?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a limitation of the `mapply` function. Hence, the only way to circumvent this is by not using `mapply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use `mapply`? This works just fine with normal indexing.

```r
position[size < 5,2] <- position[size < 5,1] + 5
position[size > 8,2] <- position[size > 8,1] - 7
```

Answer (score 0):

We could create a index to pass a `vector` of values and do this in one step (if there are multiple conditions)

```
i1 <- 1 + 2 * (size < 5) + 4 * (size > 8)
position[,2] <- position[,1] + c(5, -7)[match(i1, unique(i1))]
```